# Sorting strings+numbers in Perl

Tags: perl, sorting

I have an array with these values:

```
scores Parent=mRNA1
scores Parent=mRNA2
scores Parent=mRNA3
scores Parent=mRNA4
scores Parent=mRNA5
scores Parent=mRNA6
scores Parent=mRNA7
scores Parent=mRNA8
scores Parent=mRNA9
scores Parent=mRNA10
scores Parent=mRNA11
```

but I cannot sort them. By sorting them using `sort { $a cmp $b }`, I obtain:

```
scores Parent=mRNA1
scores Parent=mRNA10
scores Parent=mRNA11
scores Parent=mRNA2
scores Parent=mRNA3
scores Parent=mRNA4
scores Parent=mRNA5
scores Parent=mRNA6
scores Parent=mRNA7
scores Parent=mRNA8
scores Parent=mRNA9
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can isolate numbers, and compare/sort them [numerically](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) using `<=>`

```
@arr = map $_->[0], sort{ $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] } map [ $_, /(\d+)/ ], @arr;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Sort::Naturally](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Sort-Naturally-1.03/lib/Sort/Naturally.pm) for this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Sort::Naturally;

chomp( my @arr = <DATA> );
print "$_\n" for nsort @arr;

__DATA__
scores Parent=mRNA9
scores Parent=mRNA10
scores Parent=mRNA11
scores Parent=mRNA1
scores Parent=mRNA2
scores Parent=mRNA3
scores Parent=mRNA4
scores Parent=mRNA8
scores Parent=mRNA5
scores Parent=mRNA6
scores Parent=mRNA7
```

Output:

```
scores Parent=mRNA1
scores Parent=mRNA2
scores Parent=mRNA3
scores Parent=mRNA4
scores Parent=mRNA5
scores Parent=mRNA6
scores Parent=mRNA7
scores Parent=mRNA8
scores Parent=mRNA9
scores Parent=mRNA10
scores Parent=mRNA11
```